# Why this aem sling folder locale is missing?

Tags: java, aem, sling

[image]

Above provide image Locale Name is missing es_tx?

Answer (score 1):

es_tx is not a valid locale. I think you meant es_mx (Spanish Mexico). TX is not a country code (it's probably for Texas) but Spanish is not a formal language in Texas.

I can probably make a lot of political jokes about this but this isn't the right forum :)

The reason why you don't see a locale name for this is simply because es_tx is not a mapped to any locale definition in AEM. It can be made to recognise this as a locale but don't think this is your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed to previous answer es_tx is not a valid locale. AEM supports all the locales that Java SE has. When you are creating a locale page make sure you refer to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html to see if it is supported